# How to write Exif to a JPEG with TwelveMonkey's ExifWriter class

Tags: java, jpeg, exif, twelvemonkeys

Im using the [TwelveMonkey's](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) lib to read Exif data from jpeg like:

```
       try (ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(input)) {
            List<JPEGSegment> exifSegment = JPEGSegmentUtil.readSegments(stream, JPEG.APP1, "Exif");
            InputStream exifData = exifSegment.get(0).data();
            exifData.read(); // Skip 0-pad for Exif in JFIF
            try (ImageInputStream exifStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(exifData)) {
                return new EXIFReader().read(exifStream);
            }
       }
```

therefore I have a `CompoundDirectory` with a bunch of `Entry` elements. But how do I use the `ExifWriter` to a jpeg. Using it to write to the outputstream just corrupts the jpeg (image viewers think it is a broken tiff).

***Update***:
What I like to achieve is reading a jpeg to a `BufferedImage`, also reading exif data, scaling it and then compressing it to jpeg again retaining the exif data (ie. writing the previously read data to the scaled out jpeg). For this I currently use some verbose version of `ImageIO` methods. Here is the basic code to do this currently: https://gist.github.com/patrickfav/5a51566f31c472d02884 (exif reader seems to work, writer not of course)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TwelveMonkeys Exif package (the `EXIFReader/EXIFWriter`) is quite low-level, and is designed to be efficient for use by `ImageReader/ImageWriter` implementations. It's still fully usable as a general purpose meta data package, but it might require more work on your part, and some knowledge of the container format used to carry the Exif data.

To write Exif data to a JPEG, you need to write an `APP1/Exif` segment as part of the [normal JIF structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_files). The `EXIFWriter` will write the data you should put *inside* this segment only. Everything else must be provided by you.

There are multiple ways of achieving this. You can work with a JPEG on binary/stream level, or you could modify the image data and use ImageIO meta data to write the Exif. I'll outline the process of writing Exif using the `IIOMetadata` class.

From [JPEG Metadata Format Specification and Usage Notes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/jpeg_metadata.html#image):

> (Note that an application wishing to interpret Exif metadata given a metadata tree structure in the `javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0` format must check for an `unknown` marker segment with a tag indicating an `APP1` marker and containing data identifying it as an Exif marker segment. Then it may use *application-specific code to interpret the data in the marker segment*. If such an application were to encounter a metadata tree formatted according to a future version of the JPEG metadata format, the Exif marker segment might not be unknown in that format - it might be structured as a child node of the `JPEGvariety` node. Thus, it is important for an application to specify which version to use by passing the string identifying the version to the method/constructor used to obtain an `IIOMetadata` object.)

The `EXIFReader` will be your "application specific code to interpret the data". In the same way, you should be able to insert an `unknown` marker segment node with an `APP1` (normally, that would be `0xFFE1`, but in the ImageIO metadata, only the decimal representation of the last octet as as string is used, thus the value is `"225"`). Use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and write the Exif data to that, and pass the resulting byte array to meta data node as "user object".

```
IIOMetadata metadata = ...; 

IIOMetadataNode root = new IIOMetadataNode("javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0");
IIOMetadataNode markerSequence = new IIOMetadataNode("markerSequence");
root.appendChild(markerSequence);
    
Collection<Entry> entries = ...; // Your original Exif entries

// Write the full Exif segment data
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// APPn segments are prepended with a 0-terminated ASCII identifer
bytes.write("Exif".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
bytes.write(new byte[2]); // Exif uses 0-termination + 0 pad for some reason
// Write the Exif data (note that Exif is a TIFF structure)
new TIFFWriter().write(entries, new MemoryCacheImageOutputStream(bytes));

// Wrap it all in a meta data node
IIOMetadataNode exif = new IIOMetadataNode("unknown");
exif.setAttribute("MarkerTag", String.valueOf(0xE1)); // APP1 or "225"
exif.setUserObject(bytes.toByteArray());

// Append Exif node 
markerSequence.appendChild(exif);

// Merge with original data 
metadata.mergeTree("javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0", root);
```

If your original meta data already contains an Exif segment, it's probably better use:

```
// Start out with the original tree
IIOMetadataNode root = (IIOMetadataNode) metadata.getAsTree("javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0");
IIOMetadataNode markerSequence = (IIOMetadataNode) root.getElementsByTagName("markerSequence").item(0); // Should always a single markerSequence

...

// Remove any existing Exif, or make sure you update the node, 
// to avoid having two Exif nodes
// Logic for creating the node as above

...

// Replace the tree, instead of merging
metadata.setFromTree("javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0", root);
```

I don't like the ImageIO metadata API particularly, because of the extreme verboseness of the code, but I hope you get the idea of how to achieve your goal. :-)

---

PS: The reason image viewers think your image is a TIFF, is that the Exif data *is* a TIFF structure. If you only write the Exif data from a JPEG to an otherwise empty file, you will have a TIFF file with no image data in `IFD0` (and possibly a thumbnail in `IFD1`).

Comment: thx for the quick reply harald! I updated my answer. If I can convert the exif data to IIOMetadata that would be the prefered way

Comment: But let's say I want to read a JPEG, completely ignoring its metadata, and write a small fixed set of Exif metadata I get from somewhere else. In other words I want to completely replace the Exif metadata, and I don't know if the original JPEG even had Exif metadata to begin with! How would I get the original `IIOMetadata` instance? The "`...`" in your example leaves out this important piece. :)

Comment: Yes, I deliberately left that out. Your use case is different from the OP.  The *original* metadata could be obtained from reader.getImageMetadata. A “blank” one can be obtained from writer.getDefaultImageMetadata.

Comment: Thanks, Harald; `imageWriter.getDefaultStreamMetadata(param)` is really useful to know! But now … how do I add an Exif entry? Just one simple Exif entry is all I need and I can figure out the others. Are you saying I should skip the `Directory` and construct `TIFFEntry` instances? I opened ticket https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/issues/586 . I can also post the question here in Stack Overflow if you prefer.